# SwiftUI: Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have made this Main Menu view and every image will take to another view for that I have put a navigation link but if I click on one image(any image) it will work for one time only then I get this error. Please help me out, I will be super grateful

I am getting two errors first is: **SwiftUI encountered an issue when pushing a NavigationLink. Please file a bug.**

second is:  Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILOVd.png)

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainMenu: View {
    var columns = Array (repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 15), count: 2)
    @State var selected : MainMenuData = data[0]
    @State var show = false
    @Namespace var namespace
    @State var isLinkActive = false
    @State var isLinkActive1 = false
    @State var isLinkActive2 = false
    @State var isLinkActive3 = false
    @State var isLinkActive4 = false
    @State var isLinkActive5 = false
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
          //  ZStack{
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    
//                    HStack{}
//
//                    // due to top area is ignored.
//
                       // .padding ([.horizontal, .top])
                    
                    // Grid View.
                    
                    LazyVGrid (columns: columns, spacing: 25){
                        
                        ForEach (data){travel in
                            
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10){
                                
                                Image (travel.image)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width: 230,height: 260)
                                    .cornerRadius(15)
                                    .padding(.top,-65)
                                //assigning IDs..
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        
                                        selected = travel
                                        
                                        if selected.id == 0
                                        {
                                            isLinkActive = true
                                        }
                                        else if selected.id == 1
                                        {
                                            isLinkActive1 = true
                                        }
                                        else if selected.id == 2
                                        {
                                            isLinkActive2 = true
                                        }
                                        else if selected.id == 3
                                        {
                                            isLinkActive3 = true
                                        }
                                        else if selected.id == 4
                                        {
                                            isLinkActive4 = true
                                        }
                                        else if selected.id == 5
                                        {
                                            isLinkActive5 = true
                                        }
                                    }
                                   
                                    .background(
                                        NavigationLink(destination: Student(), isActive: $isLinkActive1) {
                                            EmptyView()
                                        }
                                            .hidden()
                                    )
                                    .background(
                                        NavigationLink(destination: Card(), isActive: $isLinkActive2) {
                                            EmptyView()
                                        }
                                            .hidden()
                                    )
                                    .background(
                                        NavigationLink(destination: Rentalform(), isActive: $isLinkActive3) {
                                            EmptyView()
                                        }
                                            .hidden()
                                    )
                                    .background(
                                        NavigationLink(destination: FlashLaneFeatures(), isActive: $isLinkActive4) {
                                            EmptyView()
                                        }
                                            .hidden()
                                    )
                                    .background(
                                        NavigationLink(destination: EasyPassFeatures(), isActive: $isLinkActive5) {
                                            EmptyView()
                                        }
                                            .hidden()
                                    )
                                 .matchedGeometryEffect(id: travel.id, in: namespace)
                            }
                        }//foreach
                        
                        .background(
                            NavigationLink(destination: PropertyFilter(), isActive: $isLinkActive) {
                                EmptyView()
                            }
                                //.isDetailLink(false)
                            .hidden()
                            
                        )
                       
                        
                    }//vgrid
                    .padding (.horizontal)
                    .padding(.top,5)
                    .padding(.leading)
                    
                    
                }
            //scrollview
                //.padding(.top,UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top)
                // Hero View..
           // }
           // .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
            //.background (Color.white.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
            //}
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Text("Main Menu")
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 10)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        .font(.system(size: 30,weight: .medium, design: .default))
                    
                }//toolbaritem
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Image(systemName: "bell")
                }//toolbaritem
            }//toolbar
        }
      
    }//view
}//struct

struct MainMenu_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainMenu()
    }
}
```